# Решение графа на координатной плоскости

Tags: python, graph

Есть список 1 (В нем содержатся координаты начальной и конечной точек)

Есть список 2 (В нем содержится координаты точек)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример рандомных точек на изображении

Надо найти кратчайший путь от начальной до конечной точки, проходящий по каждой точке из списка 2

Ответ: список, который состоит из последовательности точек для кратчайшего пути.

**Пример:**

*стартовая и конечная точки:*

```
start_finish = [[70, 35], [9, 17]]
```

*точки которые необходимо обойти:*

```
points = [[11, 12], [74, 40], [0, 1]]
```

*решение для данного примера:*

```
[[70, 35], [74, 40], [11, 12], [0, 1], [9, 17]]
```

Comment: я правильно понимаю, что это классичекая задача коммивояжера?

Comment: @S.H. Вроде да, по-моему

Comment: К сожалению не знаком с данным термином, но думаю что нет

Comment: "Задача коммивояжёра — одна из самых известных задач комбинаторной оптимизации, заключающаяся в поиске самого выгодного маршрута, проходящего через указанные города хотя бы по одному разу с последующим возвратом в исходный город" - у Вас просто города откуда стартовать и где финишировать - различные. Я смотрю - вроде Ваша задача не допускает какого то упрощения, которое позволило бы её решить без комбинаторного взрыва. Значит - реурсия и возрастание перебора до эн факторил, где эн - кол-вот точек кроме A и B